# Retrieve all possible combinations of dictionary recursively

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I saw many similar questions, however didn't find exactly what I need here. Any help appreciated.

I have set of Keys (K[1..M]), each Key K[i] can be mapped to any value from a set of available values for this particular Key K[i]:V[i,1..Ni]

```
K[1]: V[1,1] | V[1,2] ... | V[1,N1]
K[2]: V[2,1] | V[2,2] ... | V[1,N2]
...
K[M]: V[M,1] | V[M,2] ... | V[1,NM]
```

I need to implement RECURSIVE function returning enumerable of all possible combinations of K-V mappings

For example:
With given set:

```
K1: 1 | 2 | 3
K2: 4 | 1
```

Combinations will be the following:

```
(K1:1, K2:4)
(K1:2, K2:4)
(K1:3, K2:4)
(K1:1, K2:1)
(K1:2, K2:1)
(K1:3, K2:1)
```

Ideally the function should be like this:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> EnumerateAllPossibleCombinations(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> getAvailableValuesForKey)
{
    ...
    yield return ...;
}
```

Using of function (draft code):

```
var allCombinations = EnumerateAllPossibleCombinations<string, int>(new[]{"K1","K2"}, k=>{
   switch k
   {
      case "K1": return new[]{1,2,3};
      case "K2": return new[]{4,1};
   }
   ThrowException("Unknown key");
});
```

Result for example above should be 6 dictionaries with 2 key-value-pairs in each

I'm trying to avoid using Cartesian Product, since I need to receive dictionary after dictionary (allCombinations.ElementAt(1), allCombinations.ElementAt(2)), while Cartesian has to be executed entirely for all combinations before it can return first dictionary.

Comment: What do you need the Func for?  Isn't that simply another loop within your main function?  Or do you plan on passing in a predicate?

Comment: So for your example you would want it to return 6 dictionaries each with two entries?

Comment: I updated the question text with additional clarifications based on your comments.

Comment: why in the world people downvote this question? what's wrong with it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
public static IEnumerable<IDictionary<TKey, TSource>> EnumerateAllPossibleCombinations<TKey, TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TKey> keys,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>> getAvailableValuesForKey)
{
    if (keys == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keys");
    }

    if (getAvailableValuesForKey == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("getAvailableValuesForKey");
    }

    return keys.Any() ? 
           EnumerateAllPossibleCombinationsImp(keys.Distinct(), getAvailableValuesForKey) :
           Enumerable.Empty<IDictionary<TKey, TSource>>();
}

private static IEnumerable<IDictionary<TKey, TSource>> EnumerateAllPossibleCombinationsImp<TKey, TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TKey> keys,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>> getAvailableValuesForKey)
{
    if (!keys.Any())
    {
        yield return new Dictionary<TKey, TSource>();
        yield break;
    }

    var firstKey = keys.First();
    var values = getAvailableValuesForKey(firstKey) ?? Enumerable.Empty<TSource>();
    bool hasValues = values.Any();

    foreach (var value in values.DefaultIfEmpty())
    {
        foreach (var dictionary in EnumerateAllPossibleCombinationsImp(keys.Skip(1), getAvailableValuesForKey))
        {
            if (hasValues)
            {
                dictionary.Add(firstKey, value);
            }

            yield return dictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

First the reason for two methods is so the `ArgumentNullException`s for `keys` and `getAvailableValuesForKey` will be thrown when the method is called instead of when the resulting `IEnumerable` is iterated.  Next we do a quick check to see if `keys` is empty and if it is we just return an empty `IEnumerable`.  If it is not empty then we call the second method that contains the main implementation.

The second method is recursive, so first we setup our default case which is `keys` being empty in which case we yield an empty dictionary (This is why we do the empty check in the first method).  Then we break the problem down by taking the first item from `keys` and retrieve the `values` for that key.  If `getAvailableValuesForKey` returns `null` for that key we will treat it as if it returned an empty set instead (this could instead be treated as an exception case if desired).  We then check to see if there are any `values` and we iterate over them, but in the case that there are none we use `DefaultIfEmpty` to insert one default value.  That is done so that we will do one iteration for an empty set of values.  Then we do a recursive call passing in the rest of the keys by use `Skip(1)` and for each returned dictionary we check if we had any values for the key and if we did then we add that key and value pair to the dictionary and either way we yield the dictionary.  The idea is that eventually the recursive calls will hit the case where there are no keys and just return an empty dictionary that will then have entries added to it as the recursive calls unwind.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will essentially take the form of (pseudocode):

```
foreach (var key in dictionary)
    foreach (var value in dictionary)
        yield return new KeyValuePair(key, value)
```

If you need to pass in a predicate to constrain the values, you can insert it thusly:

```
foreach (var key in dictionary)
    foreach (var value in getAvailableValuesForKey)
        yield return new KeyValuePair(key, value)
```

The actual code will look closer to this (untested):

```
foreach (var x in dictionary)
    foreach (var y in dictionary)
        yield return new KeyValuePair (x.key, y.value);
```

Comment: Why not just iterate the `Keys` and `Values` properties instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this is essentially Cartesian Product solution which I'm trying to avoid here. I added that note to the question.